# How to retrieve and display Contact Name with corresponding SMS body in Android app?

Tags: android, sms, contacts

Thanks in advance for your help.

I would like to make an activity that would look similar to the starting activity of native android messaging app: contact image, contact name, first few words of the message body.

So far with the help of this website I could figure out how to retrieve Senders phone numbers in a list view. Here is a part of the code I am using:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    List<SMSData> smsList = new ArrayList<SMSData>();
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);

    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < c.getCount(); i++) {
            SMSData sms = new SMSData();
            sms.setBody(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body"))
                    .toString());
            sms.setNumber(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address"))
                    .toString());

            smsList.add(sms);

            c.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    c.close();

    setListAdapter(new ListAdapter(this, smsList));
```

My question is, how to retrieve and display Contact Name with corresponding SMS body???

The closest solution I found so far is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451617/names-not-displayed-on-retrieving-sms-details?answertab=votes#tab-top), but I cannot figure out how to put together my code and this solution.

Comment: the code you link to seems quite straightforward, I don't understand where your issue is?

Comment: add [getContactName](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451617/names-not-displayed-on-retrieving-sms-details?answertab=votes#tab-top) method in your class and also permission in manifest file then pass Contact number as :`smsList.add(getContactName(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).toString()));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added proper permissions needed for doing this operation in your manifest? i.e
 
 needed for that to be in your manifest for that operation, read these tutorial and download source code available and try that
http://www.technotalkative.com/android-fetch-inbox-sms/
Hope that it will work....

Comment: Thanks, I did add all necessary permissions. I see your tutorial does what my app code is already doing. I need fetch Contacts' names alone with SMS's bodies in ListView

Answer (score 0):

After looking more closer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451617/names-not-displayed-on-retrieving-sms-details?answertab=votes#tab-top) example actually helped me.

Thanks to everyone